# Completeness/Compactness of a subset in a normed linear space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness, normed-spaces

> Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be the normed linear space consisting of the sequences $a=(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$, for which the corresponding series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges absolutely, with norm $\|a\|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n|$.
>
> Let  $e_k\in X$ be the sequence  whose $k$-th term is $1$ and all other terms are zero and let $E=\{e_k : k\in \mathbb{N}\}$.
>
> Then which of the following are true?
>
> 1. $E$ is complete in the norm $\|\cdot\|$.
> 2. $E$ is bounded subset of $X$.
> 3. $E$ is a closed subset of $X$.
> 4. $E$ is a compact subset of $X$.

All I can say is :

$E$ is bounded as norm of any element in $E$ is $1$.

$E$ is not closed because $(e_k)\rightarrow(1,1,1,\dots)$ which is not an element of $E$.

I think $E$ is not complete though I can not say anything about the proof.

$E$ is not compact I guess as it is not closed though that this not sufficient/necessary.

Please help me to see if my justification for second and third bullets are sufficient and please help me to see more clearly what would first and fourth bullets be.

Thank you

Comment: $E$ *is* closed. But  $(e_k)$ is not Cauchy. In fact $\Vert e_j-e_i\Vert=2$ for all $i\ne j$. So $(e_i)$ has no Cauchy subsequence. What does this tell you about the compactness of $X$?

Comment: I do not understand why $E$ is closed.. could you please explain that

Comment: For example, it has no limit points (this follows from what I wrote earlier).

Comment: Oh my Bad... If it have limit points then i have to worry if they are in $E$ or not to check if it is closed.. If there are no limit points there is no point... a Very valid point...

Comment: but i do not get the connection of having no Cauchy sub sequence with compactness... for sequential compactness, there should be at least some convergent sub sequence but we do not have cauchy.. so no point of convergence... Is this what the point is all about?

Comment: Normed spaces are metric spaces. So showing $E$ is not sequentially compact suffices (though it's not hard to find an open cover of $E$ with no finite subcover, take open balls of radius $1$ about each $e_i$).  If no subsequence is Cauchy, then no subsequence converges. So $E$ is not sequentially compact.

Comment: yes yes that is what i said, I am just asking if what i have said is enough....

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Can i just say from this that it is complete vacuously....

Comment: No. $X$ is complete and certainly has Cauchy sequences. Showing completeness of $X$ is not entirely trivial. But if $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $X$, each coordinate sequence $(x_n(i))_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to some $y_i$ in $\Bbb R$. Show that the sequence $y=(y_i)$ is in $X$ and that $(x_n)$ converges to $y$ in $X$.

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449348/show-that-ell1-cdot-1-is-complete) for the argument that $X$ is complete.

Comment: @DavidMitra : Oh yes... closed subset of complete space is complete and $l^1$ is complete and this $E$ is a closed subset of  $l^1$ so, $E$ is complete..

Comment: You changed the question. $E$ is complete, vacuously (or use your argument)...

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand... I did not change the question :O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What David Mitra said is quite concise and true. To sum up.

1)There are only trivial Cauchy sequences in $E$. So $E$ it can be shown that it is complete.

3)Now  as stated above, $E$ is closed.

4)$E$ is not  compact because there is a sequence that has no convergent subsequence, since it has no Cauchy subsequences and every convergent subsequence must be a Cauchy subsequence (David Mitra).

2)Also $E$ is bounded because  $\operatorname{diam}E=\sup\{\|x-y\|:x,y\in E\}=2$.

Comment: Do you mind to make this community wiki?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik,yes of course. make it:)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik,it's ok i found the button:P

Comment: You wrote: *There are not Cauchy sequences in $E$.* Certainly, a constant sequence is Cauchy. But any Cauchy sequence in this space must be eventually constant. Maybe *"There are no non-trivial Cauchy sequences in $E$."* would be a better wording.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Furthermore, $E$ is complete. Thus the reasoning of $4)$ is incorrect. It is not compact because there is a sequence that has no convergent subsequence, since it has no Cauchy subsequences and every convergent subsequence must be a Cauchy subsequence. (This is David Mitra's argument.)
Also, I must point out that $E$ is bounded although it is not totally bounded. These are different concepts in metric spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. True, True, True, False.

Comment: this is not even a hint...

Comment: The answer should help to prove, now that you know what to prove.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.